# Printing a Variable from a BST

Tags: haskell

I'm trying out an exercise where I have to print out a root node of a bst. They are telling me to use `data BinSearch x y = Empty | Node x y (BinSearch x y) (BinSearch x y)` (meaning a binary search tree either has nothing in it or it does) and the signature, `result :: BinSearch x y -> Maybe y`. I need to run the program like,

```
> result None
Nothing
> result (Node 0 44 None None)
Just 44
```

I'm a bit confused on how to do this. If I had control over the signature, it'd be easy, but I don't understand how to go about this.

The only thing I've come up with is

```
data BinSearch x y = None | Node x y (BinSearch x y) (BinSearch x y)
result :: BinSearch x y -> Maybe y
result (Node a b None None) = b
```

but the error I get there is that it couldn't match v with BinSearch x0 y0.

EDIT: I have fixed all transcription errors, apologies. The problem is now stated EXACTLY as it was in the book.

Comment: The specification, as you've described it, is wrong.

Comment: @dfeuer can u elaborate?

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon: there's simply no way to return the whole root node when the return type is `Maybe y`.  You can only expect to return the value of the right node.

Comment: And you can't return a `Maybe a` one time and a `BinTree x y` the other. And `BinTree` can't possibly be lower case anyway.

Comment: `binSearch` needs to be capitalized - e.g. `data BinSearch ...`

Comment: @Rufflewind But all Maybe means is that it's either nothing or something. Why would that pose a problem in finding the root node?

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon: your specifications say `result (Node 0 23 Empty Empty) == Node 0 23 Empty Empty`.  What you have on the right side is *not* a `Maybe y`, but a `BinSearch x y`, which contradicts your type specification `... -> Maybe y`.  Therefore your problem is ill-posed.

Comment: @Rufflewind My bad, I just figured out what you meant. Error on my part. I just fixed EVERYTHING, hopefully.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon: I assume by `Maybe 44` you meant `Just 44`?

Comment: @Rufflewind Sorry, I'm having a slow day lol.

Answer (score 1):

Two small hints: first, it must be `BinSearch` with a capital `B`. I suspect this was a transcription error on your part. Second is a syntax hint; your pattern needs parentheses, like this:

```
result (Node a b None None) = ...
```

This is not a complete solution; but will get you over this hurdle and into the next (more interesting) error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I'm dumb. You just have to put "Just 44" at the end. My problem was that I didn't know that "Just" was built in.

Comment: `Just` is not a built-in function. It simply the constructor of a datatype, which is declared as `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`.